# How to import go file from internal folder?

Tags: go

I have a go project whose structure is:

```
- internal
  - client.go
main.go
go.mod
```

go.mod:

```
module github.com/zhaoyi0113/eml-transaction

go 1.17

require github.com/go-resty/resty/v2 v2.7.0

require golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20211029224645-99673261e6eb // indirect
```

client.go:

```
func SendTransaction() {

}
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)
import "github.com/zhaoyi0113/eml-transaction/internal"
func main() {
  SendTransaction()
}
```

The problem is that `SendTransaction` is invisible in main.go. When I run `go build`, I got below error:

```
./main.go:11:8: imported and not used: "github.com/zhaoyi0113/eml-transaction/internal"
./main.go:36:2: undefined: SendTransaction
./main.go:36:18: undefined: TransactionRequest
```

I don't understand why the import is not used. What is the right way to import it?

Comment: You cannot import files.

Comment: You need to have proper dependency injections and by using structs and interfaces that export those functions. Read here on [google wire](https://github.com/google/wire)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out how it works. I have to use `internal` as the prefix to call this method.

```
internal.SendTransaction(internal.TransactionRequest{})
``
```